# JavaScript match function returns null

Tags: javascript, android, regex, null, match

I am creating a program on android for android game Word snack. It would compare searched string and words from file (not yet from file, just testing it with strings) (see the rules). But, whatever I do, I am still getting error: `"Script Error: Cannot read property 'length' of null"` on line:

```
if((from_file.match(new RegExp(from_file[i], "g") || [])).length != (searched.match(new RegExp(from_file[i], "g") || [])).length)
```

in function `compare_words(from_file, searched)`. I am using `(string.match(new RegExp(searched_str, "g") || [])).length` for finding number of occurrences in string as already showed on stack overflow. But I am still geting that error. Can anybody help me? Than you. :D

```
function OnStart()
{
    lay = app.CreateLayout( "linear", "" );
    var from_file = "dedo";
    var searched = "odod";
    if(compare_words(from_file, searched) == true)
    {
        txt = app.CreateText(from_file + ": true");
        txt.SetTextSize( 32 );
        lay.AddChild( txt );
    }
    app.AddLayout( lay );
}


function compare_words(from_file, searched)
{
   if(from_file.length == searched.length)
   {
       var b = 0;
       for(i = 0; i < from_file.length; i++)
       {
           if((from_file.match(new RegExp(from_file[i], "g") || [])).length != (searched.match(new RegExp(from_file[i], "g") || [])).length)
           {
               b = 1;
               break;
           }
       }
       if(b == 0)
       {
           return true
       }
       else
       {
           return false
       }
   }
   else
   {
       return false
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not

```
(from_file.match(new RegExp(from_file[i], "g") || [])).length
```

But

```
(from_file.match(new RegExp(from_file[i], "g")) || []).length
```

You are `or`ing the regex, not the match results.